# Android spinner don't show items when runs on real device (Apk)

Tags: android, android-spinner

When I test my app in android studio (emulator or inside my smartphone debug mode) all works fine.

So when I generate an APK file to distribute my app, it doesn't show list of items inside my spinner and i can not select any items

This is a part of my layout with spinner

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/plantType"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/seleziona_plant_type"
        app:met_floatingLabel="normal"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imagePlant"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

this problem is cross version device, it's appenend with all device

In build.gradle (app) I've this error on section dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile ('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    }
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and this is error on appcombat-v7 library

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 24.0.0, 23.2.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.0.0 and com.android.support:design:23.2.
```

This is my proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /home/claudio/Android/Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

some advice?

Comment: Are you using any third party spinner library ?

Comment: @Nithinlal I'm using this https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner

Comment: Got it when you update the question

Comment: check this issues https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=show&type=Issues it may help .I don't know how u implement the code spinner so I can filter out the issue

Comment: connect a mobile device, use the app. In Logcat, you might see what's the issue.

Comment: What is the version of the emulator and the device you are using

Comment: @Nithinlal both is 6.0.1, but i've tried also with lower version android 4.0.3

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS there's not error in my Logcat :(

Comment: Are using any google API service to bind data to the spinner

Comment: @Nithinlal no in bind data ... anyway i use a google services

Comment: Both signed apk and debug apk have separate SHA1 key make sure that u integrated correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141542/discussion-between-nithinlal-and-claudio-pomo).

Comment: This is the issue due to using the same library with different version

Comment: Change both support:appcompat and support:design to 24

Comment: @Nithinlal i've put a version 24 but doesn't work ;(

Comment: Share your proguard. it will be proguard issue

Answer (score 0):

Check for the permissions(in case you are loading data into spinner from storage) as you could be launching your app on lower API and your device is having different or higher API than emulator.

Comment: If there is user permission it will be same as in device and the emulator I think so..Anyway try

Comment: for api level below 21 not need for runtime permission for api level above 21 you will need to ask for permission at runtime

Comment: the problem is not about permission, I'm using correct way to manage this.